# Passing native types between dll's

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have 2 dll's written with c++cli (let's name them dll A and dll B).

In dll A I have a function defined as:

```
void func(System::String^ str1, std::string& str2);
```

In dll B I try to call the said function as:

```
 System::String^ str1 = gcnew System::String("whatever");
    std::string str2;
    func(str1, str2);
```

This generates a compile error which states that "cannot convert from std::string to std::basic_string, allocator>*"
However I noticed this is not the case only for std::string, but for any native type (except primitives) (e.g cannot convert from class to class *). If I have the function in the same dll in which I'm making the call, everything compiles fine. Does anyone know why this happens?

Note: in dll B I have `#using <A.dll> as_friend`
Note2: both dll's are compiled using the same compiler options.

Comment: Both of those dll are .NET/CLI dll's. So why not just add them as reference to a .NET Project and use them that way? Otherwise COM might be a approach. As .NET is in large parts a replacement for .COM, there is a lot of interoperability between those two technologie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop)

Comment: I'm not saying the way I'm doing it is the best way or something like this. I'm just wondering why it's behaving like this in this particular scenario.

Comment: You are relying on .NET metadata in the assembly to provide the function declaration.  That can be troublesome since it was designed for .NET declarations and not native C++ template types.  #include is the alternative, I can't tell if that will cause problems as well without seeing the outer declaration.

Comment: std::basic_string is the native C++ String. It has not much in common with the .NET String. We know the native C++ String is a array. With .NET String that is not nearly as clear. If you append two strings, there is a decent chance that the new string instance will just be "consists of these two seperate strings". And once you throw in stuff like string interning or that they compare via value equality, stuff is really different. Plus what hans said about Metadata. Managed/Unmanaged Interop is a area I try to stay clear off in general. Too many headaches.